# displaying an image from a computer

Tags: java, image, file, netbeans

I am trying to display an image from a file (saved on my computer) The image I am trying to load is called "maze.jpg." From the code I have so far, it is able to run and compile, but whenever I run it, I get a blank window. What am I doing wrong?? I am using netbeans to code this. Here is my code:

```
package mazedisplay;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MazeDisplay extends Component
{
   BufferedImage b;

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      g.drawImage(b,0,0,null);//supposed to draw an image at these coordinates
   }

   public MazeDisplay()
   {
      try
      {
         b = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MazeDisplay\\maze.jpg""));//reads the file

      }

      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();

      }


   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
   {
        if (b == null) 
        {
         return new Dimension(800,800);
        } 
        else 
        {
           return new Dimension(b.getWidth(null), b.getHeight(null));
        }
   }

   private static String[][] readMaze(String filepath) 
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filepath));

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
       return null;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[][] maze = readMaze("C:\Users\Owner\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MazeDisplay\maze.jpg");
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Maze");//sets the frame to say "maze"
        System.out.println(new File("maze.jpg").getAbsolutePath());

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)//this is for closing the program
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        Component add = f.add(new MazeDisplay());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);// makes sure we can see it

        JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel content = new JPanel();

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, and from that I assume I would have to give a path such as this:

("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\maze.jpg") ?

Comment: depends upon where the image is located. if it's in the project folder, you can use the relative path aswell. add `e.printStackTrace()` in the try-catch-block for loading the image to see, if any exceptions are thrown

Comment: All righty! but what does e.printStackTrace () do?? Also, I added it in there, and apparently what I got was this:

    run:
    javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
     at mazedisplay.MazeDisplay.<init>(MazeDisplay.java:23)
     at mazedisplay.MazeDisplay.main(MazeDisplay.java:58)
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` prints the stacktrace of the exception (all methods with their lines in the stack from the location where the exception was thrown to the method where the exception was caught). most likely `new File("maze.jpg")` doesn't point to the file with your image. you can check by printing the full path (`file.getAbsolutePath()`).

Comment: I see, but where would I add the file.getAbsolutePath() ?

Comment: just anywhere, it's just to see where your file actually points to. you could for example add it as first line in main, like `System.out.println(new File("maze.jpg").getAbsolutePath())

Comment: Got the path! :D turns it its just this: C:\Users\Owner\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MazeDisplay\maze.jpg.. but my window still comes out blank, and i still get this:

javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at mazedisplay.MazeDisplay.<init>(MazeDisplay.java:24)
 at mazedisplay.MazeDisplay.main(MazeDisplay.java:79)

Comment: have you updated the path in the code to the correct one?

Comment: I believe I did, if not... then I must be missing a few more things

Comment: actually this new code you just added doesn't make much sense. just replace "maze.jpg" in the `MazeDisplay` constructor with the correct path and everything should work.

Comment: I did that. still did not work.. I think it may have something to do with me not actually using the JPanel and JPanel content, because the way I am thinking, is that they are fart of the frame, and because nothing is being displayed in there, the window is blank.

Comment: no further exceptions?

Comment: never mind.. it worked!!! turns out, i had to actually go and drag my maze jpg in to the actual path, and change the documents part to my documents...

Answer (score 0):

```
JComponent display = new JComponent() {
    BufferedImage bi = loadImg();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
    }
};

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maze");
frame.setContentPane(display);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

private static BufferedImage loadImg(){
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    try{
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File("yourfile.jpg"));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

        bi = new BufferedImage(200 , 100 , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0 , 0 , 200 , 100);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(e.getMessage() , 20 , 20);
    }

    return bi;
}
```

This will either display the loaded image, or another image with the errormessage from loading the image, if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I was able to get it to work! =)  thank you so much for helping me! sorry for all those comments XD but what does this code do: 

Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0 , 0 , 200 , 100);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(e.getMessage() , 20 , 20);
    }

Comment: it creates a new image with white background and the errormessage in black. every image has it's own graphics object that can be used to paint on it.